# GitLab: is there a concept of project similar to GitHub?

Tags: github, gitlab

In GitHub there is a concept of "project" which allows to group issues as implementation of a cross-cutting multi-project implementation. For example, introducing a new logging framework is likely to affect multiple code projects so you can in GitHub create a new "project" which groups all issues related to this cross-cutting effort. Is there anything similar in GitLab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GitLab provides the same-named structure - [GitLab projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/).

You can even [import it](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html) from GitHub or other platforms into GitLab. And if that doesn't satisfy the needs completely, there's still [the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/).